# Under what situation is Pythons __get__ called?

Tags: python, python-3.x, python-descriptors

When I create a Descriptor class and have an instance of that Descriptor, I can access the `__get__` by accessing the `object.descriptor_object`

e.g.

```
class Descriptor:
    
    def __get__(self, *args):
        return 10
    
class A:
    
    a = Descriptor()

a = A()
a.a # Prints 10
```

However how do I access these without creating a Descriptor object inside another class?
I am trying to utilize the `property` class without using it as a decorator, e.g.

```
def get_five(*args):
    return 5

five = property(get_five)
five # <property object at 0x...>, not returning 5
```

In this case, if I have `a_property` how do I call `__get__` on it like it was inside another class?

As a Bonus, does this not print `5`

```
class A:
    
    a = Descriptor()

    def __init__(self):
        self.b = property(self.getter, self.setter)
    
    def setter(*args):
        print("setter")
        
    def getter(*args):
        print("getter")
        return 5

a = A()
a.b
```

Comment: What you are asking doesn't make much sense. You can always access it directly, in any case, using `five.__get__`... but *why do you want to do this*?

Comment: So `__get__` is called when a descriptor is a class member of a class and it is accessed either via the class or an instance. This is a fundamental aspect of descriptors - their whole purpose is to let classes customize attribute lookup, storage, and deletion. Read more info [here in the Descriptor HowTo guide](https://docs.python.org/3/howto/descriptor.html)

Comment: So, `five` will never return anything other than the object being referenced by the name `five` in that scope

Comment: @juanpa.arrivillaga oh, I need to have a descriptor inside a class to utilize, I should not have it outside?

Comment: If by utilize, you mean "will follow the descriptor protocol" then *yes*. The descriptor protocol exists to allow you to customize lookup, storage, and deletion of attributes. You do this by creating a descriptor as a class variable. The protocol is not invoked outside of that context.

Comment: @juanpa.arrivillaga I made a small edit again, woud you be able to identify why "5" is not being returned, but instead it is printing the descriptor object again. Cheers

Comment: **As I already explained and as you would read in the documentation I provided**, the descriptor protocol is only invoked for *descriptor objects that are class variables*.

Comment: @juanpa.arrivillaga Right I see, cheers.

Comment: You cannot use a `property`, nor anything else, in order to make it so that a function you define will be called when accessing a variable by name. In other words, you cannot make it so that the expression `five` does anything other than give the value of the variable named `five` (or raise a `NameError` or `UnboundLocalError` if such a variable isn't defined). Whatever reason you have for wanting to do this, the solution to your real problem is going to be something else. Please see https://xyproblem.info/